# Quadratic With Periodic Coefficents

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, transcendental-equations

I've come across a problem that results in the equation:
$t^2 -2t\sin t -2\cos t -2 = 0$

I've tried to do this analytically but I can't figure it out. At this point, I just want to know if it's even possible for something like this to be solved exactly. So can an equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, where $a, b, \text{or } c$ are a trig function, be solved?

Comment: Since $t$ is both inside and outside trig functions, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). Typically, these require numerical methods to determine approximate solutions.

Comment: How is that "quadratic"?  Did you accidentally forget the $2$ in $t^2$?

Comment: Yes whoops, ill fix that now

Comment: I guess there is no fixed point anymore after the edit. What have you tried? “I tried to do this analytically” can be specified.

Comment: Tried Vieta's formulas, and the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the equation to a complicated  power function equation by:

$$t^2-2t\sin(t)-2\cos(t)=2$$

Use the complex definitions of the function:

$$t^2-it e^{-i t}+ i t e^{i t}- e^{- i t}-e^{it}=2$$

A transformation $x=it$:

$$-x^2-xe^{-x} -e^{-x} +xe^x-e^x= -x^2-e^{-x}(x+1) +e^x(x-1) =2$$

Now use the limit definition of $e^x$:

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac{a+ x}a\right)^{\pm a}=e^{\pm x}\implies -x^2-\left(\frac{a+ x}a\right) ^{-a}(x+1)+ \left(\frac{a+ x}a\right) ^a(x-1)=2 $$

Therefore your equation can be a power function as $a\to\infty$:

$$\boxed{-x^2-a^a(x+a)^{-a}(x+1)+ a^{-a}(x+a) ^a(x-1)=2}$$

For $a=10$, the expanded polynomial of $x$ is: $$-400000000000000000000 - 400000000000000000000 x - 180000000000000000000 x^2 - 48000000000000000000 x^3 + 16350000000000000000 x^4 + 20442000000000000000 x^5 + 9486000000000000000 x^6 + 2846400000000000000 x^7 + 628140000000000000 x^8 + 107972000000000000 x^9 + 14903420000000000 x^10 + 1678600000000000 x^{11}+ 155353000000000 x^{12} + 11821800000000 x^{13} + 736440000000 x^{14} + 37209600000 x^{15} + 1501950000 x^{16} + 47310000 x^{17} + 1121000 x^{18} + 18800 x^{19} + 199 x^{20} + x^{21} =0\implies x=i t=2.0374…,-1.78203…$$

using $a=90$ gives [**this result**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0%3D-2+-+90%5E90+%281+%2B+i+t+%29+%2890%2B+i+t+%29%5E%28-90%29+%2B+t+%5E2+%2B+i+90%5E%28-90%29+%2890+%2B+i+t+%29%5E90+%28i+%2B+t+%29)

$$t≈\pm 2.13207…-0.015…i$$

while the true real root of your equation is: $$t=\pm 2.1320…$$

If the inverse of this power function equation can be found, then we will have an inverse function for your problem. For $a\in\Bbb N$, you will have a better polynomial approximation. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Someone more familiar with the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) could help since it can find the series expansion, with closed form coefficients of $x^n-c x$, so maybe the linked theorem also help find the inverse of the boxed equation.

Comment: The polynomial mathjax may not render

Answer (score 1):

Using graphics or inspection, the zero of function
$$f(t)=t^2 -2t\sin( t) -2\cos (t) -2 $$is just above to $\frac {2\pi}3$
$$f\left(\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)=-1-\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9}=-0.241108\cdots$$
Expanded as series
$$f(t)=\left(-1-\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9}\right)+2\pi \left(t-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(t-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)^2 +$$
$$\frac 13 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac { \left(2 \pi -3 \sqrt{3} (n-1)\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\left(3 (n-1)+2 \sqrt{3} \pi \right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)} { n!} \left(t-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)^n$$

Truncate to some low order and use series reversion to obtain, as an *approximation*,
$$t=\frac{2 \pi }{3}+x-\left(\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{3}{4 \pi }\right)
   x^2+\left(\frac{2}{9}+\frac{9}{8 \pi ^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3} \pi }\right)
   x^3-$$ $$\frac{\left(3645+1350 \sqrt{3} \pi +1152 \pi ^2+176 \sqrt{3} \pi ^3\right)
   }{1728 \pi ^3}x^4+O\left(x^{5}\right)$$ with $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2 \pi }-\frac{2 \pi }{9}$.

This truncated series gives an explicit expression : its decimal representation is
$t=\color{red}{2.132020}087\cdots$ while, as given by Newton method, the solution is $t=\color{red}{2.132020146}\cdots$